# How to Display image on Linkbutton to look attractive in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi i want to display an image on a Linkbutton to make it looks attractive in asp.net
any one have idea how to do it...

Answer (score 14):

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ...>
  <img src="yourimageurl" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: That is great. but if i want Hover effect.What i need to do .i don't to go with scripting

Comment: Black_Crown: put a css class on the image and in your css definition, use the :hover pseudo attribute like this .yourclass:hover{...}

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `ImageButton`?

Comment: i want to dispaly text in between that so i want to use link button