# Image in Linkbutton

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Display image on Linkbutton to look attractive in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394346/how-to-display-image-on-linkbutton-to-look-attractive-in-asp-net)

hi i am using this code

for display image in link button but i want to show text in between Link button...
can anybody help me regarding this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394346/want-to-dispaly-image-on-linkbutton-to-look-attractive-in-asp-net

Comment: @darasd: I wouldn't call this a duplicate.  The question is vague enough that it sounds like there is a desire for both image and text.

Comment: Rsolberg, so does his other question. 90% match of words.

Comment: I didn't even look to see who the asker was!  Now voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ImageButton

- [w3c schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_imagebutton.asp)
- [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/justinsaraceno/archive/2008/11/05/linkbutton-with-image-and-text.aspx